# How to get the most recent created subdirectory by using linq?

Tags: asp.net, linq, directory

I am very new to Linq. But I am trying to write a function to get the most recent created subdirectory by using `Directory.GetDirectories(rootPath).Where(...)`. Is it possible and how to I continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var info = new DirectoryInfo(rootPath);    
var latestDirectory = info.GetDirectories()
                          .OrderByDescending(d => d.CreationTime)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
```

You can easily change name of `DirectoryInfo` class property you'd like to sort by.

[`DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3e2f6e5.aspx) returns array of `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`, so you can easily order that directories by `CreationTime` and return the first one.

**VB.NET solution:**

```
Dim info As New DirectoryInfo(rootPath)
Dim latestDirectory As DirectoryInfo = info.GetDirectories() _
                                           .OrderByDescending(Function(d) d.CreationTime) _
                                           .FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: No! GetDirectories returns array of DirectoryInfo: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3e2f6e5.aspx

Comment: Wrong, DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories does.

Comment: How come when I tried to use =>, it is always automatically changed to >=? In addition I couldn't use var. I changed it to string. BTW, I am using vb.net.

Comment: What language do you use? Is it C# or VB.NET? I'll post a VB.NET solution in a second.

Comment: also, what is definition for d?

Comment: It's a variable used within Lambda Expression - you don't need to declare it anywhere.

Comment: I couldn't use either var or d (without definition).

Comment: Ok, so last question: which version of .NET framework do you use?

Comment: So try the second solution: for VB.NET.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25090/discussion-between-gaolai-peng-and-marcinjuraszek)

Comment: Got it. Thanks very much. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get specific DirectoryInfo information to determine the creation time. Try this.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(rootPath);
var directory = di.GetDirectories()
                  .OrderByDescending(d => d.CreationTime)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```